# Sources on the Topic Source Code Security/Authenticity

Tags: resource-request, undergraduate, resource-information

I have been asked so be the second on grading a paper a Student is going to write about "Creating a methodology for ensuring Code Security/Authenticity". Sadly this is not my field of expertise.

Now I'm looking for some basic information about methods or software that already exists, so I can get a baseline understanding of the Topic.
These are the Questions that are currently on my mind:

- Is there already an established best practices?
- What are commonly used Methods?
- What are the most important points when looking at Code Security?

The student will hopefully provide some basics in his paper but I would hate to go into this blind  just to be fair to the student.
I would be grateful if anyone could point me toward  any good introductory material?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[David A. Wheeler](https://dwheeler.com) has a collection of essays, including several on software security (particularly targeting Unix/Linux).

There are lots of tools around, including sophisticated checkers that are build on LLVM, like [klee](http://klee.llvm.org). You'll also find discussions like ["Top 12 Open Source Security Tools"](https://spectralops.io/blog/top-12-open-source-code-security-tools) with a bit of searching.

There are lots of standards, look e.g. at ["Security Standards in Software Development"](https://www.kiuwan.com/security-standards-in-software-development).